# Override a Standard button and navigate to another URL or a vf page

Tags: visualforce

I have a created a simple VF page

```
<apex:page standardController="Delivery__c" sidebar="false" >
    <apex:relatedList list="Addresses__r"/>
</apex:page>
```

Now I have added this VF page to a section on a custom Object : Delivery__c pagelayout . And is shown as expected.

[image]

Now when i click on new address it opens in that section and not in a new window. Is there any way that I can override this standard button and navigate to the url i want.[image] . I want to do this on my VF page and not by overriding the standard buttons in salesforce Buttons, Actions and Links section.

Comment: Its confusing. You created a custom button ? is Create Address that button to which you have assigned that VF page ?

Comment: I created a VF page and added to a section on Delivery__c page layout. In that visual force page I am just displaying the related list Addresses__r. so I am able to see the related list as expected as shown in img1 . But when I click on New Address button ( on vf page which i am displaying as a section ) it opens inside  that section and not in a new window. Is there a way that i can override the New Address button in relatedlist.

Answer (score 3):

You could use some simple JavaScript for this:

```
<apex:page standardController="Delivery__c" sidebar="false" >
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        if(event.target.tagName === "BUTTON" && event.target.innerText === "New Address") {
            event.preventDefault();
            window.open("{!URLFOR($Action.Address__c.New, null, [])}", "_blank");
        }
    })
    </script>
    <apex:relatedList list="Addresses__r"/>
</apex:page>
```

You may need to add additional parameters in the `[]` to link the parent Id. You'll want to base it off the URL that's presented when you click the button by default. It'll have two params, like CF00N000000000000 and CF00N000000000000_lkid.

Comment: Hi , Thank you for the quick reply. I have https://na3.salesforce.com/a01/e?CF00N5000000ADhH2=Delivery+1&CF00N5000000ADhH2_lkid=a0Y5000000AneHd
 &retURL=%2Fapex%2Fnotesandrelatedlist%3FId%3Da0Y5000000AneHd%26core.apexpages.devmode.url%3D1 .   How do I pass these two parameters in URLFOR , please guide me

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript to set the target on all links in that page to open in a new window.

Add this just before `</page>` to your VF markup:

```
<script>
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

  for (var i=0, len=links.length; i < len; i ++) {
    links[i].target = '_blank';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This won't work for AJAX-loaded elements, though.